# Could not find class 'com.google.gdata.client.calendar.CalendarService'

Tags: android

I am trying to use CalenderService from this class but it is giving me " Could not find class 'com.google.gdata.client.calendar.CalendarService' " error at runtime, i have imported gdata.client libraries. Have tested on both android versions 2.0 and 4.0, but still getting this error.
Any suggestions?

thanks

Comment: You have included the actual libraries in your development environment?

Comment: yes.. but still it is giving me this error

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to add support library so to do that, just Right click on your project from Project Explorer goto Android Tools -> Add Support Library.
And clean your project after adding the libraries.

Comment: have done with it, just as u said but still getting the same error       Could not find class 'com.google.gdata.client.calendar.CalendarService'   . i Have included all the external jars through buildpath.

Comment: is the libs folder present in your project explorer?
If not create a libs/ directory in Eclipse, and add then add libraries to the Eclipse build path. And clean your project after that.

Comment: It is not working , after adding them there in libs/ folder.. same error. Basically i just want to sync my own app with google calendar..   Any Suggestion??                                                          Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might not be exporting the library. In the Project Properties window, Java Build Path section - make sure the library is checked on the Order / Export tab.